# How to fix the braille printing?

Tags: c#, braille

My project is a Tamil to Braille translation system. I want to make an print-out of a Braille document, and used the normal printer code in c# (printer dialog), but my embosser printer is just printing garbage instead of my document.

Is there any special way to print with an embosser printer from C#? Can you help me to fix this problem? My printer is index braille Basic D version 3, and my document is a braille document.

Comment: Most likely it requires some special code. The GDI printing outputs an image, but I suppose the braille printer requires letters or dots. If you are lucky it just requires an image of 3x(2*n) pixels to be happy. You need to consult the printer documentation or at least update your question with the model of the printer.

Comment: I translate it into dots (that mean I used braille unicode) but my braille printer gives garbage infinite result. can you help me.

Comment: I updated my question I hope to consider it

Answer (score 0):

You need to send raw data to the printer. I have done this with version 4 printer, but I think it will work with version 3 too.
Check this class from Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091